# Matrix Multiplication in C language

Tags: c, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply 2 dimensional matrices in C language. I have furnished below the code for your reference. When I try to print 'myC', I keep getting zeros out. Where am i going wrong ? I've tried multiple things and still can not figure this out. Has anyone got ideas, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define mysize 4 

int myA[mysize][mysize];
int myC[mysize][mysize];
int i,k;
int j,l;
int total;
int iLimit;
int jLimit;

void printMatrix(int iLimit,int jLimit,int myA[iLimit][jLimit]){
    i=0;
    while (i<iLimit){
        j=0;
        while (j<jLimit){
            printf ("%7d", myA[i][j]);
            j=j+1;
        }
        printf ("\n");
        i=i+1;}
}

int main(void){
    iLimit=mysize;
    jLimit=mysize;
    k=0;
    while (k < iLimit){
        l=0;
        while (l < jLimit) {
            scanf ("%d",&myA[k][l]);
            l=l+1;
        }
        k=k+1;
    }

    printMatrix(mysize,mysize,myA);
    myC[i][j]=myA[i][k]*myA[k][j];
    printf("\n");
    printMatrix(mysize,mysize,myC);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the entire code that you expect to multiply your matrices? `myC[i][j]=myA[i][k]*myA[k][j];`. You know enough about loops to realize why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

the multiplication of the matrices has to be done for all the elements. so it should be in a nested for loop. what you are doing in your code

```
myC[i][j]=myA[i][k]*myA[k][j];
```

this statement would multiply only one element of the matrix that is represented by the index `i,j,k` (out of bound in your code). the above statement has to be kept inside 3 nested for loops. something like this..

```
for (i=0;i<m;i++)
{
   for(j=0;j<q;j++)
   {
       myC[i][j]=0;
       for(k=0;k<n;k++)
           myC[i][j]+= myA[i][k]*myA[k][j];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This only multiplies two elements, where i j and k are all out of bounds.

```
 myC[i][j]=myA[i][k]*myA[k][j];
```

It should be in a triple-loop, where you set i j and k appropriately.

Comment: i think you mean "triple loop"